# A classic example of using rvest gives an fatal error

Tags: fatal-error, rvest

I repeat the classic example from the page

https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

I load the package and the page:

```
library(rvest)
lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
```

After entering the line

```
lego_movie %>% 
html_node ("strong span") %>% 
html_text () %>%
as.numeric ()
```

message appears about a fatal error.

The same situation with attempts to do the same on other pages.

Version R - 3.3.3, version of rvest - 0.3.2

All actions are performed in the RStudio environment version 0.99.903

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If possible, could you please add the exact error message that you are getting, it may help others in finding and answering the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course:   [link](http://i013.radikal.ru/1704/74/ff585e5e642d.png)

Comment: That page is outdated. The first line should use `read_html`, not `html`. Besides that, I run the code without error (using `rvest` 0.3.2.9000)

Comment: Yes, of couse, That page is outdated. I used read_html. Thanks, I'll try to install a new version of rvest

Comment: A repeat the example from command line RTerm. No problem! It is a problem of RStudio or something with installing it on my computer or in my settings this package. Maybe someone already solved the same problem with RStudio???